# Autenticación Básica Retrofit "not permited by network security policy"

Tags: android

Estoy intentando comunicarme con una API autenticada con user y pass vía Retrofit. Anteriormente me he conectado a otras API's sin autenticación y funciona perfecto. Pero en esta nueva API con autenticación no lo logro, me devuelve el mensaje "CLEARTEXT comunnication to api xxxxxxx not permited by network security policy" (las credenciales están correctas, por postman logro ver el JSON)

El código que utilizo es:

```
final String AUTH = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("username:realpass").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(
                new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();

                        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Authorization-Bearer", AUTH)
                                .method(original.method(), original.body());

                        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                }
        ).build();


Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://api-a-conectar.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

y en la interfaz:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    @GET("news/get-news/")
    Call<String> getString();
}
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal o me falta.

Saludos

Comment: Quiza te falta el archivo network_configuration, ahi debes poner las direcciones a las cuales la app hara peticiones http

Comment: Logra la conexión, lo que no logra es la autenticación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, ademas de `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` en el manifest faltaba agregar el barear: `Call<String> call = api.getString("Bearer fa1e66004352ccdvdfsthshsdt");` y desde la interface `Call<String> getString(@Header("Authorization-Bearer") String bearer);`

Con eso se realiza la conexión sin problema.

Comment: Si está es la solución entonces por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada por favorb

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas realizando peticiones a direcciones no cifradas, es decir que usan `http://` , actualmente se requiere usar `https://`.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api-a-conectar.com/")
```

Si no tienes acceso via `https://` , por el momento puedes permitir este tipo de peticiones definiendo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    ...
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

---

El valor predeterminado para las apps que se orientan a la API nivel 28 (definido en build.gradle `targetSdkVersion 28`) o a una versión posterior es "false" por default, por lo tanto no permitirán el uso de peticiones http://, por esta razón tienes que activarlo aunque es recomendable usar siempre urls https://.

Revisa:

**[Android android:usesCleartextTraffic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)**